# Checking if a string contains a Pascal integer in SML

Tags: sml, ml

Can someone help me writing a function that does that?

I tried this:

```
fun isPascalInteger (s:string) = if (size(s)=0) then return true
    else if (!(isDigit(sub(s,0)))) then return false
    else (isPascalInteger(extract(s,1)));
```

Answer (score 1):

The most convenient way to work with strings is often to convert to a list first, then use list functions:

```
fun isPascalInteger (s:string) = List.all Char.isDigit (explode s)
```